# How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error on particular kernel?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel, graphics, amd-graphics

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.03 on a Dell Inspiron 15-5547, AMD Radeon HD R7 M265 dual graphics with the fgrlx-updates drivers. Since the update to kernel 3.16.0.60, when I try to boot into my computer, I am getting this error:

```
The system is running in low-graphics mode
```

I have followed the suggestions described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) (reinstalled the proprietary drivers via apt-get).

However, the problem persists, when i boot into 3.16.0.60.
Kernel 3.16.0.59 boots without problems.

Is there a mismatch of kernel vs drivers, which should be considered a bug?
Is there something I can do in order to get graphics working on kernel 3.16.0.60?
As a temporary workaround: where can I change the default kernel my system boots into?

EDIT: The problem persisted up to and including kernel 3.16.0.67. I found a bug report in launchpad, which however had no activity. I have updated to 16.04 on the day of release due to this bug and do not have this problem any more.

Comment: This looks like a bug/regression that was introduced in kernel 3.16.0.60. You should report that.

Comment: @DavidFoerster The problem persists in  3.16.0.62. Should this be reported as a bug against the kernel, or against fglrx-updates?

Comment: I'm not sure. Try fglrx and depending on the situation someone may reassign the bug to the kernel package.

Answer (score 0):

Start your computer while  pressing these buttons: CTRL + ALT + F1 and then enter your username and password and type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -d install --reinstall gdm
sudo apt-get remove --purge gdm
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

Select  **gdm**

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: This did not work. In fact when using gdm instead of light-dm my system did not boot even when using the 3.16.0.59 kernel. I had to repeat the steps above and select light-dm. Now I am back to the original problem.

Comment: I mean did not boot in a graphical environment, even when using....

Comment: Is that video driver  is installed?

Comment: fgrlx-updates is installed (else the system would not run on the 3.16.0.59 kernel)